# How to fix IndexError while sorting a list of lists of varying sublist lengths

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I have the following list:

```
expected_ans = [[3], [1],[2],[1,2,3],[1,3],[2,3], [1,2] ,[]]
```

I am trying to order its elements by the first element in the sublist in this way:

```
sorted(expected_ans, key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure what I am missing? Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No index would work with an empty list, which the last sub-list in your sample list is.

You can instead sort by a single-item slice of each sub-list instead, which, in case of an empty sub-list, would return a empty list as the key and would place it in the front of the returning list:

```
sorted(expected_ans, key=lambda x: x[-1:])
```

This returns:

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're sorting by the last element in each list

Second, the reason that you see index error is because the last list is empty. [ ][-1] will raise IndexError because there is no element at -1 position